# Error while trying to update JupyterLab with conda

Tags: anaconda, command-prompt, conda, jupyter-lab

I have just installed Anaconda on a new machine (Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit). As I try to launch JupyterLab, I see that the package needs to be updated. However, I always get the following error:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.continuum.io\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'ssl3_get_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')],)",),))',),)
```

The same happens if I use `conda` from the prompt.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an SSL issue, are you working behind a firewall?

You can turn ssl off by editing your .condarc, which should allow you to update.

```
conda config --set ssl_verify False
```

Although I would recommend actually providing a certificate instead. I have answered this question previously here - [CondaHTTPError - SSL error while installing NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984000/condahttperror-ssl-error-while-installing-nltk/48992114#48992114), which has steps to export a CA certificate from your browser. Lets imagine you save it to C:\ca_certificates\my_certificate.cer . you can then point your conda config at it via the following command.

```
conda config --set ssl_verify C:\ca_certificates\my_certificate.cer
```

Comment: Well, I have run your first line of code and have presumably made it to update JupyterLab. However, when I launch it from either within Anaconda Navigator or the prompt I get the message: 404 : Not Found
You are requesting a page that does not exist!

Comment: from command prompt, try 'conda search conda' as a command and report what error you are seeing